# WebBrowser component in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, browser

I want to use a `WebBrowser` control in a [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) project. Ages ago, when I was using VB6, I just added the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control (`C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll`) to my form and it worked, but I'm lost in C++.

Should I load it dynamically with `LoadLibrary`, then somehow add it to my dialog window? I want to have standard features like page navigation, dynamic HTML elements, submittable forms, view page source, etc.

---

**Update:**
I installed Qt Maker and downloaded a test project from the official site. But when running/compiling I get this error:

> ```
> Could not find make command: make in the build environment
> Error while building project betalabsclient (target: Desktop)
> When executing build step 'Make'
> ```

Does anyone have any ideas? Mingw is installed, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer for your question, but you may want to try and use `Qt` and the `webkit` browser component in it.

There are several `webkit`-related samples and I assume that they may actually suit for your needs *"as they are"*.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Browser Example (ActiveQt)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/activeqt-webbrowser.html)

[HOWTO: Get QT working with Dev-C++](http://www.qtforum.org/article/16061/howto-get-qt-4-1-0-working-with-dev-c.html)